# Non Confidential OAuth2 flow

Tags: authentication, oauth2

I've been going through some documents regarding `OAuth2` confidential and non-confidential authorisation flows, namely [this](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth2-clients/single-page-apps/) and the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

From my understanding, the non-confidential flow does not require the *client_secret*, or better yet, you actually shouldn't use the *client_secret* because you're assuming anyone can get a hold of it along with the *client_id*, thus making it easier to pose as the client app.

So in order to implement the non-confidential flow, the client must first work with the *client_id* issued by the server and a *state* generated by the client. Then the client should make use of a *code* returned by the server and the same *state* value. A *redirect_uri* must also be registered with the server.

AFAIK (As far as I know) that's what distinguishes the confidential from the non-confidential flow: the confidential flow requires the *client_secret* whereas the non-confidential doesn't. Moreover, this is what defines the non-confidential flow, the lack of a *client_secret*. Am I correct in assuming this?

[Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3) doesn't seem to be specific regarding this.

Related Q, from [Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3):

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in
> [Section 3.2.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1)

What exactly sits under "*other authentication requirements*"? Isn't this any client that has to be authorised?

Comment: Should've added that the non confidential and confidential also differ in the sense that you can't refresh tokens with a non confidential client.

Answer (score 1):

A confidential client can keep/protect secrets, whereas a non-confidential client cannot.

Because non-confidential clients cannot keep secrets, the OAuth 2 specification does not allow Refresh tokens, or any kind of confidential information to be shared with such clients. This also means non-confidential clients cannot be trusted with secret or private keys.

Without such keys a client cannot authenticate itself (i.e. securely identify itself with a given client_id) with the authorization server.

Even though a non-confidential client is assigned a client_id, anyone can masquerade as that client_id. As such the authorization server deliberately limits the kind of information it will share with a non-confidential client.

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK (As far as I know) that's what distinguishes the confidential
>   from the non-confidential flow: the confidential flow requires the
>   client_secret whereas the non-confidential doesn't.

Rather than the flow itself, it's the *client* that distinguishes *confidential* from *non-confidential* (I've seen it more commonly referred to as **public**.)

**Confidential clients** are those that have the capability to store secrets. Traditional web applications with a backend server fall into this category. As secrets can be stored OAuth flows can use a client_secret in the authorization flow.

A **public client** (non-confidential client) is an application that is not capable of keeping a client password confidential. Implementing of client_secrets is not used as it can't be trusted as secure.

> What exactly sits under "other authentication requirements"? Isn't
>   this any client that has to be authorised?

I think there may be some fringe case where instead of client credentials, the resource owner has a different way of implementing client credentials. In most cases, I don't think you have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

"other authentication requirements" is probably referring to the authentication methods, other than client credentials (client id and client secret). For example, client authentication (with certificates).

Comment: Could be.. but the RFC seems a bit vague here. If you could back this up with more specific / more explicit information, that would be great.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7523 is an example with jwt tokens.